# Convert currency not working

Tags: magento-1.9, currency, currency-rates

```
    $from='HKD';
    $to='USD';
    $price=10;
    $newPrice = Mage::helper('directory')->currencyConvert($price, $from, $to); 
    echo $newPrice;
```

I use this code but it not work for me it gives error

> Fatal error: Call to a member function getCode() on string in
>   /home4/proddev/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Directory/Model/Currency.php
>   on line 194

Answer (score 1):

Look at the function `currentConvert()` the price should be an **float**

replace `$price=10;` with `$price=10.00;`

```
/**
 * Convert currency
 *
 * @param float $amount
 * @param string $from
 * @param string $to
 * @return float
 */
public function currencyConvert($amount, $from, $to = null)
    {
        if (empty($this->_currencyCache[$from])) {
            $this->_currencyCache[$from] = Mage::getModel('directory/currency')->load($from);
        }
        if (is_null($to)) {
            $to = Mage::app()->getStore()->getCurrentCurrencyCode();
        }
        $converted = $this->_currencyCache[$from]->convert($amount, $to);
        return $converted;
    }
```

**Edit:**

Go to `System>Configuration>Currency Setup` and make sure the currencies you are using are selected in the Allowed Currencies setting.

**Nb:** Your error means that the **convert** method cannot find a rate !

Comment: still not work for me

Comment: look my updated answer @jigs parmar

Comment: yes it is allowed

Answer (score 1):

Make sure which is your base currency and to which currency you want to convert

Try this

```
$from = 'USD';
$to = 'HKD';
$price = 10;
$newPrice = Mage::helper('directory')->currencyConvert($price, $from, $to);
echo $newPrice;
```

Make sure you have allowed the currency from  `System > Configuration > Currency Setup` and you have defined the currency rate in `System > Manage Currency > Rates`.

Comment: From USD to HKD is work  but HKD to USD not work